# Python Open() FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

I'm making a TV simulator for a beginners project in class and we are supposed to store all data in a .txt file, from which we should read and overwrite values. I'm already stuck at the reading part, I looked into some other questions about this but nothing seems to help. Here is what I've written so far:

```
import TV_functions
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Jocke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts')
TV = open(r'C:\Users\Jocke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\TV_data.txt')
```

Which just yields this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Jocke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\TV_simulatorn.py", line 4, in <module>
TV = open(r'C:\Users\Jocke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\TV_data.txt')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:     'C:\\Users\\Jocke\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\Scripts\\TV_data.txt'
```

I've tried what other threads have told me with the os.chdir and instead of just doing `open('TV_data.txt')` which yields the same problem...

To be clear I've made a file in python scripts folder myself named TV_data.txt.

Comment: It seems like there is no file name `TV_data.txt`.

Comment: Are you supposed to create this file?  In which case you should `open` the file for write - the default is read and the file must already exist.

Comment: The file already exists, I made it myself in the scripts folder. So I don't see where the problem is :(

Comment: The file is probably named `TV_data.txt.txt` because you named it `TV_data.txt` when saving it from a program that added an extra extension on it, and you have Explorer set to hide extensions.

Comment: THANK YOU! How did I not see this!